# why it randomly add a number or character in my barcode? how to stop it? in python

Tags: python, barcode

i'm creating a barcode using code 39 and it randomly adds number or character, how to stop it?

```
from barcode import Code39
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from io import BytesIO


rv = BytesIO()
Code39(str(), writer=ImageWriter()).write(rv)

with open('datacode.jpeg', 'wb') as f:
    Code39('grinding 091419', writer=ImageWriter()).write(f)
```

and how to add a data in it? like when i scanned it show a link like in qr code. ps; this is my personal project.

Answer (score 2):

Code 39 can include an optional checksum as the last character, see the [here](https://www.barcodefaq.com/1d/code-39/). `barcode.Code39` computes and adds the checksum automatically. This can be disabled using `add_checksum` argument. To do it, in your code replace the last line by

```
Code39('grinding 091419', writer=ImageWriter(), add_checksum=False).write(f)
```